# Last DIV disappears when any other DIV is hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm building a sidebar navigation with small dots to indicate different section of the current page

My end goal is to enlarge the dots on hover, and show the title of the section

The problem is that the last dot(DIV) disappears when you hover over any of the other dots

HTML:

```
<div id="side-bar">
  <div class="side-bar-nav-dot"></div>
  <div class="side-bar-nav-dot"></div>
  <div class="side-bar-nav-dot"></div>
  <div class="side-bar-nav-dot"></div>
  <div class="side-bar-nav-dot"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#side-bar {
    position:  fixed;
    height: 100%;
    right:  10px;
    top:  40%;
    z-index:  9999999;
}

.side-bar-nav-dot {
    background:  black;
    height:  10px;
    width:  10px;
    margin-bottom:  20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:  9999999;
}

.side-bar-nav-dot-grow {
    height: 20px;
    width:  20px;
    transition:  .3s;
}

.side-bar-nav-dot:hover {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    height: 19px;
    width:  19px;
    transition:  .3s;
}
```

[Click here for Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddeason37/yhzqw8zt/23/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yhzqw8zt/33/ is closer

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the position from hover class:

```
.side-bar-nav-dot:hover {
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    height: 19px;
    width:  19px;
    transition:  .3s;
}
```

Comment: Did you try that in the fiddle?

Comment: And do all the dots stay in place?  The goal is to only have the one to expand in size, and all the other dots remain in place

Comment: @DevonDeason man you can try it yourself, it works i swear all dots in the fiddle in their places and the hover one is growing

Answer (score 0):

Early I posted another answer, which actually was bad. Here is new one. It works like it should.

https://jsfiddle.net/yhzqw8zt/38/

```
<div id="side-bar">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="side-bar-nav-dot" style="background-color: red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="side-bar-nav-dot" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="side-bar-nav-dot" style="background-color: green"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="side-bar-nav-dot" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="side-bar-nav-dot" style="background-color: black"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#side-bar {
    position: fixed;
}

.side-bar-nav-dot, .wrapper {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.side-bar-nav-dot:hover {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    height: 19px;
    width: 19px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is great!  By chance, do you have the explanation for why the last dot disappears?

Comment: @DevonDeason It have something with `position: absolute`. The `absolute` dot hovers up, **literally**, and the next dot is located right in the same place. You can see this effect, if you add colors to your original (not working code). In other words, the **last** dot not disappears. Instead, the next dot after the hovered moves to one position up.